# Failed to execute script docker-compose Laravel

Tags: python, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have been currently working on Laravel application using Docker and i run this command successfully: `docker-compose up -d --build`

I have been trying to run this command in the Laravel Project:
`docker-compose exec app composer install`

And it was working fine but i don't know why this command giving me this **error** right now:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 524, in exec_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1498, in call_docker
  File "subprocess.py", line 323, in call
  File "subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1433, in _execute_child
  File "os.py", line 809, in fsencode
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
[3639] Failed to execute script docker-compose`
```

I am new to docker and don't know how to resolve this issue. I even though have tried re-installing docker again.
I have been using **ubuntu 18.10**.

**docker --version**:
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838

**docker-compose --version** docker-compose version 1.25.0, build 0a186604

**docker-compose.yml** networks:
  `

```
app-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
    - db
    - laravel_echo_server
    - redis
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    networks:
      app-network: null
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire:/var/www/html:rw
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini:rw
    working_dir: /var/www/html
  db:
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laraveluserpass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_USER: laraveluser
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    healthcheck:
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      timeout: 10s
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    networks:
      app-network: null
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:rw
  laravel_echo_server:
    build:
      context: /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/laravel-echo
      dockerfile: echo.dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      test: wget --quiet --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:6001 || exit 1z
      timeout: 10s
    networks:
      app-network: null
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.env:/app/.env:rw
  redis:
    healthcheck:
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      test:
      - CMD
      - redis-cli
      - ping
      timeout: 10s
    image: redis:5-alpine
    networks:
      app-network: null
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/data/redis:/data:rw
  webserver:
    healthcheck:
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      test: wget --quiet --tries=1 --spider https://public-chat.jamesisme.com || exit
        1z
      timeout: 10s
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      app-network: null
    ports:
    - 8000:80/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire:/var/www/html:rw
    - /home/abdullah_16f8418/Documents/G-Hire/.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
version: '3.0'
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your image try to delete them and download them again like this

```
docker-compose kill
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: i have been now getting this error while running `docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)`: **Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'**

Comment: Did you try to sudo it or can I do docker ps -a and then use the container id?

Comment: I got resolved the issue after ***re-installing docker***. THANKS!

Comment: Were your second issues solved with sudo? you can also mark your question as solved ;)

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was at line 12 in .env file for docker-compose.
I have deleted it, and that all.

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem and I would never come up that this was a problem! Thank you!
I had the same thing. In `.env` file I had a variable without any value, just `REDIS_URL` and no `REDIS_URL=`

Answer (score 1):

first use `docker-compose config` to see which env value cause the problem.

In my case:

```
...
POSTGRES_USER: '''some_user'''
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI:'"postgresql://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<db>"'
'~': null
...
```

So obviously the tilde '~' from vim on new line caused the problem.